# Counting before and after specific observations in SAS

Tags: sas

I have this SAS data set:

```
symbol     date       type
1010    01/01/2012  .
1010    01/02/2012  .
1010    01/03/2012  .
1010    01/04/2012  .
1010    01/05/2012  0
1010    01/06/2012  .
1010    01/07/2012  .
1202    02/26/2013  .
1202    02/27/2013  .
1202    02/28/2013  0
1202    03/01/2013  .
1202    03/02/2013  .
1202    03/03/2013  .
1202    03/04/2013  .
```

The data set is grouped by symbol and date where symbol is the firms.

I want to create another variable `USING SAS` to count number of days before Type=0 starting from -1 and after Type=0 starting from 1 for each firm, so the new column or variable will be like this

```
symbol     date       type    count
1010    01/01/2012  .   -4
1010    01/02/2012  .   -3
1010    01/03/2012  .   -2
1010    01/04/2012  .   -1
1010    01/05/2012  0   0
1010    01/06/2012  .   1
1010    01/07/2012  .   2
1202    02/26/2013  .   -2
1202    02/27/2013  .   -1
1202    02/28/2013  0   0
1202    03/01/2013  .   1
1202    03/02/2013  .   2
1202    03/03/2013  .   3
1202    03/04/2013  .
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are the days always consecutive? i.e. no missing dates between 2 entries for the same symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution, I've made a couple of assumptions :

- Every symbol has a type value of 0 that appears only once, with all other values missing.
- Count is the number of days between the date for type value 0 and the current record date.

  ```
  /* create source data */
  data have;
  input symbol date :mmddyy10. type;
  format date date9.;
  datalines;
  1010    01/01/2012  .
  1010    01/02/2012  .
  1010    01/03/2012  .
  1010    01/04/2012  .
  1010    01/05/2012  0
  1010    01/06/2012  .
  1010    01/07/2012  .
  1202    02/26/2013  .
  1202    02/27/2013  .
  1202    02/28/2013  0
  1202    03/01/2013  .
  1202    03/02/2013  .
  1202    03/03/2013  .
  1202    03/04/2013  .
  ;
  run;

  /* sort data, making type value 0 the first record per symbol */
  proc sort data=have;
  by symbol descending type date; 
  run;

  /* calculate difference in days between records */
  data want;
  set have;
  by symbol;
  retain date_zero;
  if first.symbol then do;
      count=0; /* set first record to zero */
      date_zero=date; /* store date for calculations */
      end;
  else count=date-date_zero; /* numbers of days from first record */
  drop date_zero;
  run;

  /* sort data back to original order */
  proc sort data=want;
  by symbol date;
  run;
  ```